# How to create a custom build on angular bootstrap using an old version?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Currently on the website is only possible to create a custom build using the newest version of angular bootstrap: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. I wanted to know if there is a way to create a custom build using an old version (like 0.12.1)?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to [Github page of the project, 'gh-pages' branch of 0.12.1 (already selected in this link)](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/5fce6efd08a69648726cbe7e8e91b2eb23dd31d8)
2. Click on 'Download ZIP'
3. Once downloaded, extract the folder from the ZIP file
4. Navigate to the extracted folder
5. start a static http server in that folder (if you have npm, [localserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localserver) should do the trick)
6. Open the page in your browser, et voilá!

This is also useful if you want to look at the examples they had for 0.12.1 in the official page

Answer (score 0):

UI-Bootstrap old versions are available in "Previous docs" dropdown, for example http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.12.1/